# How to round off the result of \pscalculate?

Tags: pstricks, pst-calculate

```
\documentclass[12pt,pstricks,border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pst-func,pst-calculate}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(1,1)
\def\q{\pscalculate{1/sqrt(5)}}
\def\a{\pscalculate{(1+sqrt(5))/2}}
\foreach \i in {0,1,...,10}{\pscalculate{\q*((\a)^(\i)-(1-\a)^(\i))},}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

I want to generate a list of Fibonacci sequence but without trailing zeros.

[image]

How to remove the trailing zeros?

Comment: People visiting here: there are a number of other pages on this site mentioning Fibonacci numbers, in particular https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51414/fibonacci-numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\psCalculate` (with an uppercase C) can accept some settings.

```
\documentclass[12pt,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-calculate,pgffor}
\def\q{\pscalculate{1/sqrt(5)}}
\def\a{\pscalculate{(1+sqrt(5))/2}}

\begin{document}
$0\foreach \i in {1,...,10}{,\psCalculate[round-mode=places,round-precision=0]{\q*((\a)^(\i)-(1-\a)^(\i))}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: due to rounding to nearest integer you can drop the second term very quickly (did not check starting with which `\i`

Comment: actually already with `\i = 1` you can drop second term... !

Comment: surprising that `\pscalculate` uses `siunitx` as dependency.

Comment: I can't resist to remark that, at the very moment you load `pgffor`, you do not need any of the other hocus pocus (sorry for the wording!): `\documentclass[12pt,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\pgfmathsetmacro\q{1/sqrt(5)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\a{(1+sqrt(5))/2}

\begin{document}
$0\foreach \i in {1,...,10}{,\pgfmathparse{int(round(\q*((\a)^(\i)-(1-\a)^(\i))))}\pgfmathresult}$
\end{document}`

Comment: you can not go beyond `\i=68` as maximal value. The error apparently comes from siunitx, but at same time it is at value 69 where Fibonacci value would need more than 16 decimal digits, is l3fp doing the computations underneath?

Comment: @marmot my remark on the formula applies you can drop the  `(1-\a)^(\i)` it serves nothing. But actually applying Fibonacci iteration iwth integers is much more efficient.

Comment: answering my question, removing the rounding done by siunitx one can go further but  already at `\i = 69` the precision is too bad and rounding to nearest integer would give erroneous result (`117669030460994.7` whereas the real Fibonacci is `117669030460994`).

Comment: @jfbu I agree with all this. My remark was only for the OP and on the fact that, if you load `pgffor`, you do not need any other package. (And you probably know much better than me the nice example on p. 640 of the pgfmanual in which the Fibonacci numbers are computed recursively, and only with integers, i.e. no rounding and so on.)

Comment: @marmot I surely do not know better than you the pgfmanual `:)`, however I know the background of page 2 of `xint.pdf` `;-)`.

Comment: @jfbu You have a clear advantage, then. ;-)

Comment: It is time to solve this puzzle [...](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/468471/87876)

Answer (score 3):

Fibonacci with simple LaTeX commands:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcounter{fiba}\newcounter{fibb}\newcounter{fibc}\newcounter{fibrun}
\newcommand\fib[1]{%
  \init\whiledo{\thefibrun<#1}{\step\stepcounter{fibrun}}\thefiba}
\newcommand\init{%
  \setcounter{fiba}{1}\setcounter{fibb}{1}\setcounter{fibrun}{0}}
\newcommand\step{\add \rotate}
\newcommand\add{\setcounter{fibc}{\thefiba}\addtocounter{fibc}{\thefibb}}
\newcommand\rotate{\setcounter{fiba}{\thefibb}\setcounter{fibb}{\thefibc}}

\begin{document}
  \newcounter{i} \newcounter{en} \setcounter{en}{20}
  the first \theen\ Fibonacci numbers:\\
  \whiledo{\thei < \theen}{$\fib{\thei}$ \stepcounter{i}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

and the same with running `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
function printFib(n)
  for i=1,n do tex.print(Fibonacci(i).." ") end
end
function Fibonacci(n)
  local function inner(m)
    if m < 2 then return m end
    return inner(m-1) + inner(m-2)
  end
  return inner(n)
end
\end{luacode*}

\begin{document}
\noindent\directlua{printFib(35)}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am curious about the Lua. Are the `inner` values kept in memory? else recursive definition like `return inner(m-1) + inner(m-2)` is exponentially inefficient...

Comment: It is under `macros/Latex/contrib/`

Answer (score 2):

> [image: mwe]

Someone should create a `rlatex` compiler at once, but meanwhile, I will settle with the `knitr` preprocess. Here the `.Rnw` file:

```
\documentclass[12pt,border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
<<Fib,echo=F>>=
Fibonacci <- function(n) {
    x <- c(0,1)
    while (length(x) < n) {nth <- length(x)
        new <- x[nth] + x[nth-1]
        x <- c(x,new)}
    return(x)}
@
\Sexpr{combine_words(Fibonacci(11))}.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun. Without rounding and without `pscalculate`. The example is literally copied from p. 640 of the pgfmanual. I confirm the first ten numbers of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/468630/121799) (but there are rumors some mathematician called Fibonacci had them even a bit earlier  *just kidding!* ;-).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\begin{document}
\tikzmath{
% Adapted from http://www.cs.northwestern.edu/academics/courses/110/html/fib_rec.html 
function fibonacci(\n) {
    if \n == 0 then {
      return 0;
    } else {
       return fibonacci2(\n, 0, 1);
}; };
  function fibonacci2(\n, \p, \q) {
    if \n == 1 then {
      return \q;
    } else {
      return fibonacci2(\n-1, \q, \p+\q);
    };
  };
  int \f, \i;
  for \i in {0,1,...,20}{
    \f = fibonacci(\i);
    print {\f, };
  };
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [Dynamic programming](https://youtu.be/e0CAbRVYAWg?t=76) can do it much better.

Comment: @GodMustBeCrazy This is a LaTeX site... and I am kind of impressed by what `tikzmath` can do in LaTeX.